# dbgetquery java.sql.SQLException: Bigger type length than Maximum

Tags: r

I am trying to fetch a decently large result set (about 1-2M records) using RJDBC using the following

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", 
    classPath="../oracle11g/ojdbc6.jar", " ")
con <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/servname","user","pswd")
data <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from largeTable where rownum < xxx")
```

The above works if xxx is less than 32768. Above 32800, I get the following exception

```
> data <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from dba_objects where rownum < 32768") 
> dim(data)
  [1] 32767    15

> data <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from dba_objects where rownum < 32989")
Error in .jcall(rp, "I", "fetch", stride) : 
  java.sql.SQLException: Bigger type length than Maximum
```

In https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/RJDBC.pdf, I see "fetch retrieves the content of the result set in the form of a data frame. If n is -1 then the current implementation fetches 32k rows first and then (if not sufficient) continues with chunks of 512k rows, appending them." followed by "Note that some databases (like Oracle) don’t support a fetch size of more than 32767."

Sorry for the newbie question but I don't see how I can tell dbGetQuery to fetch the result set in chunks of 32K only. I believe my fetch is dying because it went to fetch 512K records.

Would really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should probably expand your tags, java, sql oracle

Comment: thanks for that suggestion -- I will keep the tag at R for now because I believe the issue is in how many records dbGetQuery retrieves (in chunks). But appreciate it. Let me know if you disagree.